# Python Mysql Cursor.Execute Syntax

Tags: python, mysql, cursor

I have been looking for the proper way to do my cursor.execute line and have not found one that works for me.  Here is my code:

```
sa = 12345
alert_text = "Help me"
logtype = "Event"
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO logs(customer_id, log_type, log_entry) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", (sa,logtype,alert_text,))
```

I have tried every method which I have found (except the correct one) and get various errors from "not enough arguments" to mysql syntax errors.

As you can see, sa, logtype and alert_text are variables, not the actual text which must be inserted. I have simply added definition to each variable above as each of these can be something different each time.

Exact Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "listen.py", line 57, in <module>
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO logs(customer_id, log_type, log_entry) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", (sa,logtype,alert_text,))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1")
```

Comment: What you have looks correct. Please show the exact error and full traceback

Comment: Also I am using Python 2

Comment: did you try to remove ',' fro the end of your tuple - should make no difference but it really does look fine...